# detectChanges not working for a particular page

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-changedetection

The problem I'm facing is the `detectChanges()` which is not working for a component I was thinking that only my local server running be an issue but I tried to use [SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/api/people) to run the test, here is my ***ListUsersComponent*** component.

```
export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit {
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  avatarPic = 'none';
  tempData: any[] = [];
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadUser();
  }

  loadUser() {
    const sub = this.http.get('https://swapi.dev/api/people').subscribe((result:any)=> {
      console.log(result); //data is showing here
      console.log(result.results); //data is showing here
      this.tempData = result.results;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(sub);
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML of ***ListUsersComponent***.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Height</th>
            <th scope="col">Mass</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{avatarPic}}
        <tr *ngFor="let data of tempData; let i = index">
            <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.height}}</td>
            <td>{{data.mass}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No Result is shown on the HTML page but `console.log` shows data, here is the snapshot of the `console.log` below.
[image: console.log data]
a new thing also happened is that I create a duplicate replica of the component it worked flawlessly.
I don't know why this behaviour is happening for a particular page.
I did try to copy replica to the original page thinking that would work and whatever the issue might be sorted out but still this page persists this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The onPush change detection getting missed in this code `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` .

In components with the default change detection strategy (no `OnPush`), `this.ref.detectChanges()` can be used to trigger change detection manually.

In components with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` you can still use `this.ref.detectChanges()` to trigger change detection, but it's typically used in specific situations where you need to update the view due to external changes (`http` API call) that wouldn't automatically trigger change detection.

Working Code:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sensme)

Hope this helps :)